# prevent additional popups with javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox, popup, alert

I have an alert message for the users of my site:

```
alert("Message to users");
```

This message appears on every page that inherits the template.

I would like to create an option for users to stop additional alert messages using javascript. What I have in mind would be a check box underneath the message to stop additional messages.

Comment: You have to store their preference somewhere (probably the user record in your application database, or a user/alert table).  You can't do it in the web page, because their setting will disappear as soon as they refresh or move to another page.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Why not use localStorage ? oladitan you'll have to make a custom dialog (look at jquery UI if you're new to web developement) in order to add a custom checkbox.

Comment: @FilmJ I made a demo based on localStorage (very pretty, very red). See answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/jR8hk/

Each time you run it, or reload the page, an alert appears after one second.

But if you check the checkbox, you'll never see the alert again. It works by setting in the local computer a preference using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) as I suggested in comment.

Here are the part :

**HTML :**

```
<div id=alert>
    THIS IS A MESSAGE !
    <br><br><input type=checkbox id=alert_cb> SHUT UP
    <br><input type=button id=alert_close value = close>
</div>
<p>
    <br>normal content    <br>normal conten    <br>normal content    <br>normal conten    <br>normal content    <br>normal conten    <br>normal content    <br>normal conten    <br>normal content    <br>normal conten    <br>normal content    <br>normal conten    <br>normal content    <br>normal conten    <br>normal content    <br>normal conten    <br>normal content    <br>normal conten    <br>normal content    <br>normal conten    <br>normal contenttttttttttt
</p>
```

**CSS :**

```
#alert {
    display:none;
    background-color: red;
    z-index:2;
    position: fixed;
    left: 40px;
    right: 40px;
    top: 40px;
    height: 100px;
}​
```

**JavaScript :**

```
setTimeout(function(){
    if (!localStorage['stop_please']) $('#alert').show('slow'); 
}, 1000);


$('#alert_close').click(function(){
    if ($('#alert_cb').is(':checked')) localStorage['stop_please'] = "pleeeeaaaaase";
    $('#alert').hide();
});​
```

You might want to adapt the css if it's not pretty enough.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has this functionality built-in to the browser. I assume this is the functionality you're trying to duplicate?

There are kind of two different questions here. Are you asking how to create the alert box, or how to store the setting?

If you're asking how to create the alert box, there are a couple ways you could go at it:

1. Create your own custom alert box with that option available.
2. Use a confirm box instead of an alert.

Option 1: Looks like [@dystroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113337/prevent-additional-popups-with-javascript/12113582#12113582) has provided an example of how to do this using jQuery.

Option 2: It will pop up with an OK/cancel button. You can set the message to something like:

> "Message to Users"
>
> Would you like to prevent
>   these popups from now on?
>
> OK        Cancel

And if they hit OK, store the setting in some way to prevent popups from happening again.

Or you could change the message to something like "Press Cancel to prevent these popups in the future" if you want the user to be able to click OK by default without preventing them.

If you want this setting to persist between page loads, you'll have to store it in a database, cookie, session variable, or something.

Your code might look something like this:

```
if (/* check the setting to see if we should display a message */)
{
    var r = confirm("Message to users\n\nPress Cancel to prevent these popups in the future");
    if (!r)
    {
        // do something to store this setting
    }
}
```